# How can I keep array elements with specific arrangement in formatter style [eclipse]

Tags: java, eclipse, styles, formatter

I tried to find in formatter style preferences on eclipse to keep my array elements like that image :

[image]

Where can I find that style to modify it?
[image]

Comment: You can configure this in _Line Wrapping > Wrapping settings > Other expressions > Array initializers_. By the way `... = new String[] { ...` can be shorten here to `... = { ...` (Eclipse provides a clean-up for that).

Comment: @howlger thanks a lot. you can post this answer to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure this in ***Line Wrapping > Wrapping settings > Other expressions > Array initializers***.

By the way, `... = new String[] { ...` can be shorten here to `... = { ...` (Eclipse provides a clean-up for that: *Unnecessary Code > Create array with curly when possible*).

As the following image shown:
[image]